# 11:1 error Parsing error: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

[image: the structure of firebase]

I don't know what is wrong here. I have seen other posts but did not get answers.

The error is:

```
11:1  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token }

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely     additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-01T18_46_12_434Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

This is my code:

#### index.js

```
use-strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin= require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firestore);

exports.sendNotification= functions.firestore
    .document('Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}')
    .onWrite(event=> {});

const user_id= event.params.user_id;
const notification_id= event.params.notification_id;

console.log("User ID: " 
    + user_id 
    +"| Notifications ID : " + notification_id);


});
```

Comment: The template literal also looks incorrect. It should be `\`Users/${user_id}/Notifications/${notification_id}\``

Comment: You'd also need to define a `user_id` and `notification_id` variable somewhere in your code (unless they're globally available or something) if you are indeed trying to use a string template here.

Comment: Doesn't seem clear whether you're trying to use a string template for `'Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}'` - is [this what you're trying to do here?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing a:

• `'` in the beginning of your 'use strict' statement

• random `})` at the end of your code. Remove `})`.

• String interpolation using `${variable here}`

Try the following:

```
"use-strict"

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firestore);
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document(`Users/${user_id}/Notifications/${notification_id}`).onWrite(event => {});

const user_id = event.params.user_id;
const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

console.log("User ID: " + user_id + "| Notifications ID : " + notification_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the orphaned `});` on line 11.

I'm not sure if you are trying to use [string templating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) on line 5, but if you are, make sure you are using magic quotes (`) around your string, and ($) before the brackets in this line:

```
exports.sendNotification= functions.firestore.document('Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}').onWrite(event=> {});
```

It should look like this instead:

```
exports.sendNotification= functions.firestore.document(`Users/${user_id}/Notifications/${notification_id}`).onWrite(event=> {});
```

Comment: Are you sure the OP is trying to use a string template expression here?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you provided has some obvious syntax errors, as the other answers have indicated (there's an extra `});` at the end of your script, and you need to make sure you have quotes around both ends of the `use-strict` statement. The `the index.js file is` line at the top of your snippet looks like you made an error when creating your post, so you should move this line out of your code snippet, or if it's in your actual script, remove it or prefix it with `//` to comment it out.

Which version of NodeJS are you using? There's a chance that if you're using an older version of node, you are using an arrow function syntax that is not compatible with your version of node.

- Check your node version `node -v` against the [ES6 compatibility chart here](https://node.green/#ES2015-functions-arrow-functions).
- If your node version indicates that it does not support arrow functions, try replacing the following: `event=> {}` with `function(event) {}`

---

**Edit:** It also appears that the arrow function you provide to your `onWrite` does not match the arguments defined in the [latest NodeJS Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_for_any_change_to_a_document) for the `onWrite` method. Looks like the arrow function should take the following arguments `(change, context) => { /* method body */ }`:

```
exports.modifyUser = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userID}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    // Get an object with the current document value.
    // If the document does not exist, it has been deleted.
    const document = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null;

    // Get an object with the previous document value (update/delete)
    const oldDocument = change.before.data();

    // perform desired operations ...
  });
```

---

**EDIT 2:** You are seeing an Error for `user_id` undefined because you are not supposed to pass the literal string text of `{user_id}` to Firestore. That's just a placeholder representing a value you need to provide. You should provide a valid user id. For example, if you have a user id of `joe`, and a notification id of `1`, you should pass the values in as such: `functions.firestore.document('Users/joe/Notifications/1')`. [Read the documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_specific_document_changes)

You are also referencing the following variables in a call to `console.log`, which also appear to be undefined: `console.log("User ID: " + user_id +"| Notifications ID : " + notification_id);`. Are you setting these somewhere else in your code? I'm not seeing where they are set. If not, you need to set them somewhere before you reference them. Once these variables are set, then you need to update your call to the Firestore method as follows (note the use of back ticks *``*, not quotes). This is called a string template. Something like this (obviously use the actual values for `user_id` and `notification_id`):

```
var user_id = "joe";
var notification_id = 1;
functions.firestore.document(
    `Users/${user_id}/Notifications/${notification_id}`)
```

Comment: now after removing }); it is giving this error
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

ReferenceError: event is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\FirebasePushNotificationns\functions\index.js:7:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Looks like the arrow function you're providing to your `onWrite` method is incorrect.

Comment: now am facing this error :TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.firestore.document.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:7:28)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:733:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
after successful deployment ,in firebase function log.